# "Si no sabes de dónde soy, no me ronquen"

Tags: conjunciones, letras-de-canciones, imperativo, puerto-rico

In Bad Bunny's *P FKN R*, he often repeats the line

> "Si no sabes de dónde soy, no me ronquen"

I know that the verb "roncar" means "to snore" but in Puerto Rican slang can mean "to show off" or "to boast" according to [this site](https://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Roncar.php). My question is why does the verb take the negative imperative form "ronquen" instead of the intuitive "ronques", as Bad Bunny is directly addressing the listener based on his use of "sabes"? Is this a Puerto Rican accent thing?

Comment: There is a grammar mistake. Both verbs should be plural OR both should be singular.

Comment: To analyze reggaeton lyrics, is necessary a special site within SE. In practically all cases it is not pure and authentic Spanish, rather the opposite.

Comment: @Danielillo Who's to say that it's not "authentic"? Urban music tends to use more authentic language in its lyrics than other music. Whether or not it is considered gramatically correct is another thing and depends on many factors, including who says it, where there are from and what context they are saying it in.

Comment: "Authentic" is the Google translation for "castizo", which I wanted to put in my comment. At the time I realized it wasn't the right word, but I didn't change it. "Castizo" means *pure Castilian Spanish*.

Comment: Castizo tampoco es una buena palabra. Tiene una carga clasista (cuando menos) muy fuerte. No hay dialecto que sea más puro ni correcto que los otros. Los únicos que hablan --y que deben hablar-- "*pure Castilian Spanish*" son los castellanos.

Comment: @nopaltepec esto no está relacionado con su comentario (con lo que estoy de acuerdo), pero tengo curiosidad por qué usó el subjuntivo cuando dijo "No hay dialecto que sea más puro ni correcto que los otros" (y por qué Google Translate está de acuerdo con usted). Hasta donde yo sé, el subjuntivo se usa cuando existe la posibilidad de algo, pero no es seguro que suceda, pero este no es el caso en su comentario. Gracias

Comment: @Laith Tahboub El subuntivo se usa en muchas situaciones, y para indiciar posibilidad es una. Sin embargo, en la frase que destacas, la negación es lo que lo induce: ***No*** *hay dialecto que* ***sea***...

Comment: @Lambie - Is it perhaps an indicator that the singer has changed whom they are addressing in the middle of the sentence? "Si no sabes de donde soy" (while looking at the ringleader of a some group),"no me ronquen" (turning to address the whole group).

Comment: La discordancia de número es frecuente en algunas zonas de América por la mezla de idiomas (guaraní- español, quechua - español) pero sin despreciar a ningún dialecto, es una discordancia gramatical.

Answer (score -2):

---

Que tal? "*Si no sabes de dónde soy, no me ronquen*".

Siguiendo la línea mental, "*roncar*" es el ruido bronco que hace una persona cuando su respiración se bloquea mientras duerme, pero también es una forma de emitir algo, así, cualquier sonido realizado por la boca se interpreta como "hablar".

De esta manera, cuando se dice "*Si no sabes de dónde soy, no me ronquen*" significa "*Si no sabes de dónde soy, no me hablen*". Según los contextos también puede indicar hablar, reprender, amonestar, sermonear, abroncar...

Otro ejemplo lo tenemos en la canción "QueLoQue" de Major Lazer, cuando dice;
"*No me ronques por el cel-cel-cel-cel-cel*", con el mismo sentido, "*No me hables por el celular*", por el teléfono, en cualquiera de los contextos anteriores.

Espero haya servido. Saludos.

Diego M.

Comment: Gracias por su explicación del verbo "roncar", pero eso no responde a mi pregunta. Mi pregunta es sobre la diferencia en la conjugación entre las palabras "sabes" y "ronquen". –

Comment: No me ronquen. "Ustedes no me ronquen" , "Ustedes", se refiere también 3. pron. person. 3.ª pers. m. y f. pl. Forma que, en nominativo, en vocativo o precedida de preposición, designa, en Canarias, en parte de Andalucía y en América, a las personas a las que se dirige quien habla o escribe, sin hacer distinción de familiaridad, respeto o cortesía.

Comment: No confundir con el presente del verbo saber. Saben.

Answer (score -2):

Theres honestly no reason why. He just made a mistake there. It should have been both plural or both verbs singular.